# Play video and audio at the same time in Ionic Hybrid app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, html5-video, html5-audio, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 to build a hybrid app.
I have both video and audio file saved in phone local storage.

The video is played in html5 video element.
The audio can be played either in html5 audio element or Ionic Native Media plugin.

I want to:

1. mute the video (works)
2. play video and audio at the same time (not working).

It seems that the system does not allow two media resources to run at the same time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
D

Comment: Why do you need that in the first place?

Comment: the app uses one video with multiple language narratives. If this is achieved, then video and audio is decoupled with benefits like no need to download multiple video files.